# How to get the runtime url of sails app within mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm aware of `sails.getBaseUrl` and the fact that it is [deprecated](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-get-base-url). In the `bootstrap.test.js` while doing a `sails lift` I specify a `port: 1337`. `sails.getBaseUrl()` returns `http://localhost:1337`. I then run the tests using mocha (from within WebStorm if that matters). At the same time I'm able to do a `sails lift` at the terminal and run the same sails app on `http://localhost:1337`. Both seem to be running fine without a port conflict.

So at what location is mocha running the sails app when running the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that our tests were doing a `sails load` and not a `sails lift`. Based on the [sails lift](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-lift) and [load](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-load) documentation and the [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/app) I figured out that the port binding is not done in `sails load`. So I just added extra code for binding/unbinding the port as part of the test lifecycle.

```
before(function (done) {
    server = sails.hooks.http.server.listen(sails.config.port, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done();
    });
  });

after(function (done) {
    server.close();
    done();
  });
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just doing `.lift()` in your test?

Comment: Found this helpful, however personally I used this with `sails.lift({port: X})` -- to run my tests with running server while actual server is still running without interference before publishing

Answer (score 1):

If you're not setting it to something else, then your Sails app is starting on port 1337.  I'd check that you don't have a `PORT` environment variable set somewhere that one or the other app is using to override the default.  Unless one of the apps is running in a virtual machine like Docker, it's not possible for both of them to be running on port 1337 without conflict, so either your tests are failing silently or they're running a different port.

In Sails v0.12.x and Sails v1.0, the HTTP server is available as `sails.hooks.http.server`, so you should be able to check the port that an app is listening on with `sails.hooks.http.server.address().port`.